# How to fill a range of cells based on values in another range of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to fill all cells in B6:I6 based on if any values from Q6:AN6 are "No" in any one of those cells.

I have tried using conditional formatting, but it does not seem to be working properly when searching the full range of cells.

Comment: A little more info would be useful. Can you provide sample data and expected results. Also can you show us what you've tried so far and explain where the problem is exactly?

Comment: so if Q6 = "No" then highlight B6, if R6 = "No" then highlight C6, ...?

Comment: @ScottCraner It should be if Q6="No" then B6:I6 are all highlighted. That goes for any cell within Q6:AN6.

Comment: then use countifs()

Answer (score 2):

Select B6:I6 first, New Rule, Use formula to determine which cells to format, Format values where this formula is true and use the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF($Q6:$AN6,"No")>0
```

And format as you like